# Web API FB OAuth? How would to go about implementing it in a SPA application?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, durandal

Documentation on the net seems to be VERY scarce. The only option I can think of at the moment
is to have my SPA app break convention and to have the (initial) logged out page be different to the logged in one (eg my app).

My app is built using Durandal 2.0.0.

In one of my OAuth tests app's I've managed to implement this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) successfully. But as Durandal does not work in the same way (Server-side controller, & razor views), I'm thoroughly confused in how to achieve what I want to.

I'd like to have my app remain a single page app. But I've got little to no experience with the OAuth SDK

My only requirement is that the user log into my app using his FB account.

I've had an initial stab at this using the FB java script API, and got it working, but after discussions with another developer this side, it doesn't seem like the purpose of the java script API is to facilitate secure application login's? As the way we had it, would allow any user to pass a valid fb userId, then he would be logged into our app. :/

How would I go about achieving this process flow in a Durandal/Web API Single Page App?

User logs in using fb -> 
then on the server we get his fb userId ->
retrieve our internal appID

I'm not asking for a complete answer/for someone to do my work....
But any documentation to get me started/less confused would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://durandalauth.azurewebsites.net?

Comment: @Rainer to the rescue again :P... No not yet. Looked at the project now. Seems like what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample project which demonstrates how to use OAuth with Durandal and Web API:

[DurandalAuth](https://github.com/yagopv/durandalauth).

However there are some modifications in viewmodels needed, since router changed in Durandal 2.0.0.

Comment: This project was upgraded to Durandal 2.0  this week